# Apache Directory 2.0-M11 and Gitlab LDAP Authentication

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I'm trying to setup LDAP authentication with Gitlab v.4.0 with Apache Directory 2.0-M11 - the configuration of the Gitlab installation is done as per documentation and I see that it tries to hit LDAP. However I'm getting the following errors on LDAP end:

http://pastebin.com/SkmtqE7W

Gitlab LDAP config (gitlab.yml):

http://pastebin.com/quJ9kzJR

is there's any way to friend Gitlab and Apache Directory with minimum effort or minimum code customizations?

Thanks,
Vladimir.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the base object is correct. Is `base: 'dc=example,dc=com,ou=Users` really what is intended, that is, `dc=com` is an immediate subordinate of `ou=users`? The normal convention would be `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Terry. I've did what you advised to do but nothing changes. Errors remain the same.